# Sequelize querying a lot slower than Knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following code:

```
var apiLogger = require(__dirname + '/../configurations/logger').api;
var Knex = require('knex');
var microtime = require('microtime');
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

database = new Sequelize('MYDATABASE', 'MYUSERNAME', 'MYPASSWORD', {
  host: "MYHOST",
  port: 3306,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  pool: {
    maxConnections: 5,
    maxIdleTime: 30
  }
});

Knex.Initialize({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host     : 'MYHOST',
    user     : 'MYUSERNAME',
    password : 'MYPASSWORD',
    database : 'MYDATABASE',
    charset  : 'utf8'
  }
});

exports.test = function(req, res){
  apiLogger.info('Request made to /api/test');

  var start = microtime.nowDouble();
  database.query('SELECT id, username FROM Users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10').then(function(data) {
    console.log('query time : ' + (microtime.nowDouble() - start));
    res.json(data);
  }, function(data) {
    res.json(data);
  });
};

exports.test2 = function(req, res){
  apiLogger.info('Request made to /api/test2');

  var start = microtime.nowDouble();
  Knex.Raw('SELECT id, username FROM Users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10').then(function(data) {
    console.log('query time : ' + (microtime.nowDouble() - start));
    res.json(data);
  }, function(data) {
    res.json(data);
  });
};
```

If I execute the code in `exports.test` (an api call of `/api/test`) about 5 seconds apart from each other, the average response is about 430ms and this is the Sequelize code.

If I run the code from `exports.test2` (and api call of `/api/test2`) 5 seconds apart, the first call is 430ms but the call after that are about 100ms and that is Knex.

I should mention if I run the `exports.test` code less than a second apart from each other, I get the about 100ms response time and with the `exports.test2` code, I can wait 2-3 minutes between calls and still get the 100ms response time.

Is there some sort of configuration I am missing with Sequelize that is causing it to be much slower compared to Knex?  Why would requests made minutes apart with Knex be much faster than the same request made seconds apart with Sequelize?

Comment: Well I doubt Knex is caching since I am doing ORDER BY RAND() which makes the results different each request.  I understand why the first query for each take longer, that is because MySQL caches the data after the first request but if it was MySQL caching, both libraries would benefit unless Sequelize forces MySQL not to use the cache which A. not sure if that is possible and B. there would be no good reason for that.

Answer (score 2):

I set the default connection pool in Knex to a minimum of 10:

https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/clients/base.js#L22

That might be the reason.

You can set the number of pooled connections with:

```
Knex.Initialize({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host     : 'MYHOST',
    user     : 'MYUSERNAME',
    password : 'MYPASSWORD',
    database : 'MYDATABASE',
    charset  : 'utf8'
  },
  pool: {
    max: 5
  }
});
```